# Powershell: Upload .html Master Page and generate .master

Tags: powershell, master-page, csom

I am attempting to upload a new Master Page to a SharePoint 2013 site using Powershell.

I am copying the `.html` file to the "Master Page Gallery" list successfully but I cannot find any way of having the `.master` file generated without manually visiting the Design Manager in my web browser.

Is it possible to upload a `.html` Master Page through Powershell and have the `.master` generated so I can set it as the default Master Page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found I needed to add it, check it out, call update, check it in and publish it. So:

```
    $web = Get-SPWeb $site

    $folder = $web.getfolder("_catalogs/masterpage")
    $files = $folder.Files
    $mPage = Get-Item "C:\path to your\masterpage.html"
    $file = $files.Add("masterpage.html", $mPage.OpenRead(), $true)
    $file.CheckOut()        
    $file.update()
    $file.CheckIn("")
    $file.Publish("")
```

Comment: I had to do something similar to this. Previously I was calling `.update()` on the File but I needed to call `.update()` on the list Item instead